# Using Keras for predicting next word

Tags: keras, neural-network, deep-learning, nlp, lstm

I have a sequence prediction problem that I approach as a language model. 
My data contains 4 choices (1-4) and a reward (1-100) .
I started using Keras but I'm not sure it has the flexibility I need.

1. This is how the model's architecture looks :
   [image: Train]

I'm not sure about the test phase. One option is sampling:

[image: 2]

And I'm not sure how to evaluate the output of this option vs my test set.

Another option is to give the trained model a sequence and let it plot the last timestep value (like giving a sentence and predicting last word) - but still having x = t_hat.

is it possible in Keras ? I can't find examples like this.

2. Besides passing the previous choice (or previous word) as an input , I need to pass the second feature, which is a reward value. The choice are one-hot encoded , how can I add a single number with an encoded vector?

EDIT :
This is the training phase (haven't done the sampling yet) :

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(64, input_shape=(seq_length, X_train.shape[2]) , return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dense(y_cat_train.shape[2], activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, y_cat_train, epochs=100, batch_size=10, verbose=2)
```

Comment: You must explicitly confirm if your system is LSTM, what kind of LSTM and what parameters/hyperpameters are you using inside.

Comment: Thanks @M.F this looks better now.

Answer (score 0):

Google designed Keras to support all kind of needs and it should fit your need - YES.

In your case you are using the LSTM cells of some arbitrary number of units (usually 64 or 128), with: a<sup><1></sup>, a<sup><2></sup>, a<sup><3></sup>... a<sup>< Ty></sup> as hidden parameters. Note: Your last index should not be 3, instead is should be Ty.

I would suggest checking https://keras.io/utils/#to_categorical function to convert your data to "one-hot" encoded format.

Comment: I am using `to_catagorical`  , for my true labels (aka `y`) - but not when they are inserted as inputs (e.g. when `X<t> == y<t-1>`)  . Should I use encoding in input as well ? What if I need to pass 2 features , one is truly categorical (1-4 values) and the other is discrete (1-98 values) - should I encode them both ? If only one is encoded, I can't pass it with the other

Comment: Yes, both input and the output need to be translated to OH notation.

Comment: I meant should I encode the numeric feature as well ? Or should I just concatenate it to the one-hot vector of the categorical feature ?

Comment: Won't I lose the meaning of the numeric value when turning it to a categorical one ?

Comment: @M.F ask another question for that don't confuse this one, but generally you encode and decode things.